# Sum to Infinity of Trigonometry to $\pi$

Tags: summation, infinity, pi

For

$$y=\sum_{n=0}^a2\cdot2^n\cdot\tan\left(\frac{45}{2^n}\right)\cdot\sin\left(\frac{90}{2^n}\right)^2$$

I am currently working on a proof with a good friend of mine that involves adding more and more triangles to the sides of a regular polygon but keeping the longest diagonal constant until eventually, it becomes a circle.  And we ended up with this formula.

4-sided regular→ 8-sided regular→ 16-sided regular→ 32-sided regular→... →n-sided regular

(When n tends to infinity, the area will be equal to that of a circle with the longest diagonal as diameter)

We have already tried Geometric Sequence Infinite Sum, but there does not seem to have a common ratio.

Moreover, we have used our calculator to input the numbers up to 128[(sin ...] and we get the value of 3.140... which is very close to π But we can't be completely sure that the infinity sum really equals to π.

That is why we really need your knowledge of Maths to solve this.

Is there a way to prove that when $a$ tends to infinity, $y$ tends to $\pi$?

Thanks in advance and Happy Holidays Everyone! :D

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Thanks for the tip :D I will edit this right away!

Comment: Jolly Christmas and Happy Holidays to you, My Good Fellow! :)

Comment: Thank you, and Happy Holidays to you too! Let me know once you've edited the question, then I'll probably upvote :)

Comment: Hey by the way, Shaun, can you tell me how can I type Equations Symbols when I submit my Question?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$2\tan A\cdot\sin^22A=2(4\sin^3A\cos A)=(3\sin A-\sin3A)2\cos A$$
$$=3\sin2A-(\sin4A+\sin2A)=2\sin2A-\sin4A$$

which clearly shows [Telescopic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) form

Answer (score 0):

When I come across things like these: (if you do not need to prove it manually)
[Wolfram Alpha computation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(sum+of+(2%5E(n%2B1)*+tan((pi%2F4)%2F(2%5En))+*sin((pi%2F2)%2F(2%5En))%5E2)+from+n%3D+0+to+n+%3D+inf)+%3D+pi)

Comment: Thank you! I have heard of Wolfram before, but is there a manually proof for this question?

Comment: Easy to fool yourself here. If the sum happened to be $\pi + 10^{-16}$ then WA would still say True to your query. Just [try this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(sum+of+(2%5E(n%2B1)*+tan((pi%2F4)%2F(2%5En))+*sin((pi%2F2)%2F(2%5En))%5E2)+from+n%3D+0+to+n+%3D+inf)+%3D+3.14159265358979) (it's $\pi$ up to 15 digits). In this case it seems it evaluates both sides numerically (to floating point accuracy) and checks if they agree. But it doesn't tell you that this is what it does.

Comment: To check this try to ask WA to just [evaluate the sum](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(sum+of+(2%5E(n%2B1)*+tan((pi%2F4)%2F(2%5En))+*sin((pi%2F2)%2F(2%5En))%5E2)+from+n%3D+0+to+n+%3D+inf)), it doesn't evaluate it to $\pi$ symbolically.